# Laravel - Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am making a search page in Laravel and cant understand how to use the paginate method for this usage.

I have used it else where, but not like this.

So my route is:

```
Route::get('search', function()
{
  $q = Input::get('srch-term');
  $searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
  $query = DB::table('blogs');

  foreach($searchTerms as $term)
  {
    $query->where('blogtitle', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
        ->where('frontpage', '1')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
  }

  $results = $query->get()->paginate(15);
  $countBuilds = count($results);
  return View::make('search', compact('results')); 
});
```

That gives me the error in the title. If i dont use the paginate method then it works fine.

Where am I going wrong?

P.S. As a side note, I know I shouldn't be doing my DB things in the route, still getting my head around how to use functions from controllers etc in routes but thats not for here.

Comment: You cannot call paginate like this. You have to have Eloquent collection.

Comment: Try to just remove `->get()` in the `$results = $query->get()->paginate(15);` row

Comment: No create blog eloquent class and make `whereIn` with query ids. Then paginate.

Comment: @Rolice it is also allowed with query builder, is not it? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#usage

Comment: This snippet was from else where. However without using query builder and simply putting the query onto one line: `$results = DB::table('blogs')->where('blogtitle', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(15);` we have success :)

Comment: @user2921557 yeah it is without `->get()` method... `$results = $query->paginate(15);`

Comment: @user3714582 create an answer, of your comments in order to be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::get('search', function()
{
  $q = Input::get('srch-term');
  $searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
  $query = DB::table('blogs');

  foreach($searchTerms as $term)
  {
    $query = $query->where('blogtitle', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
        ->where('frontpage', '1')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
  }

  //remove ->get()

  $results = $query->paginate(15);
  $countBuilds = count($results);
  return View::make('search', compact('results')); 
});
```